# Compare values of a PHP array with a large table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, normally I would do something like this in PHP if I compared just few values:

```
// I want to get 1
$a = array(1,2);
$b = array(2);

// It produces 1
$result = array_diff($a, $b);
```

But in this case, `$b` is a large table in MySQL with millions of rows and retrieving it to PHP would be crazy, so my DBMS (MySQL) must do the work.

How could I do something like:

```
-- I need treating $a as a column 
SELECT $a NOT IN (SELECT id FROM b);
```

**Example**

*table B*

```
|id|
 2
 3
 4
```

*array A*

```
array(1, 2, 3, 5);
```

*Result*

`A - B = A - INTERSECT(A,B) = [1, 5]`

**Example 2**

[This is](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37628/55440) exactly what I need for SQL server. Any ideas to do something similar in MySQL?

Note: A has about 5000 ids, so:

```
SELECT 1
UNION SELECT 1
UNION SELECT 1
UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 5
...
```

...produces `#1064 - memory exhausted`

Comment: This sounds like it has nothing to do with PHP. If you post some information on your database structure you may get some help. Setting up something at www.sqlfiddle.com would be even better.

Comment: @miken32 I think it's not necessary knowing the database structure, I just want to compare ids to ids

Comment: @Alberto So you want to get the IDs that does not exists in the DB, right?

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux Yes, that's it

Comment: @Alberto Look at: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37628

Comment: @Alberto It may help, I think something like this exists in MySQL. If I find something, better I'll notice you.

Comment: @Alberto: Also this with small edits or a temp table to store the ids. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6731835/1084531

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` the variables in the array `$a` in PHP and use that in your `SQL` query to retrieve the data, It would efficient in you case.

```
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($a), '?'));
$sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM galleries
    WHERE id IN ($in)"
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5541/1) to prove that the `SQL` query will return the desired output.

EDIT :

> According your new requirement, You could do the array comparison in
>   the  PHP side because You have to somehow bring up the result from
>   MySQL to eliminate the result from PHP array.  If you retrieve the
>   array `$a` from another table then we could have done something like a
>   join. But in this case we cannot do it. Also you mentioned that the
>   MySQL table has large number of rows so I assume PHP array will anyway
>   remove only couple of items from the results after bringing it to the
>   memory.

Comment: Thanks... But this wouldn't produce the same result as I posted. If galleries had my $b column with `2` and I put `1, 2` in the `IN` operator, It would return `2`, and I need getting `1`

Comment: @Alberto Use `NOT IN` instead

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux Using `NOT IN` would return 0 rows

Comment: @Alberto Well, explain more clearly what you need to do because it seems confusing a little. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @Alberto Are you trying to return some rows excepted those with the $b column that has a value of the one of the $a values?

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux I am going to make an edit. Just 2 minutes

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux As for the question, my answer seems to work, check the fiddle if you want. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5541/1

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux I have added another example

Comment: @Fawzan Your example doesn't  work as I want. See my first comment and the new example, please.

Comment: @AlbertoFernández I modified my answer. I am afraid this is the best I can give.

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux would be great to have your input as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the values exist or not, you can try this one

```
<?php
$some_id = "100";

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($some_id); // i use escape to compare IP ADDRESSES. you can remove it
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE id = '$id'");
if (!mysql_num_rows($result))
{
echo "Not Exists";
}
else
{
echo "Exists";
}
?>
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the JOIN NULL query:

```
strSQL = "SELECT t2.id 
          FROM tableB t1
          RIGHT JOIN
            (SELECT id 
             FROM tableB 
             WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$arrayA).")
            ) t2
          ON t1.id = t2.id
          WHERE t1.id IS NULL";
```

Also, depending on how large `$arrayA` is, consider appending to temp table and join above, replacing sub query with temp table.