# Delete server file as per database id

Tags: php, mysql, file

I have a rackspace hosted server. I have an application to upload files in the server and also store in mysql database.

The files get uploaded with the primary key id and the extension of user's choice like `doc`, `jpg`, `zip`, `pdf` etc - Example: `111.jpg`

Now I have deleted few ids in mysql database from backend thus the files remained in the directory.

Now how can I deleted those files whose ids are deleted in the database but files remains in the server?

Comment: Why didn't you delete the files when you deleted the IDs?

Comment: @Chris Why did the chicken cross the road? ^_^

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6731797/3536236) looks like what you're looking for.

Comment: What's wrong with `unlink` function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 0):

Well you will need to have the filename and the path of that file in order to delete the file from the directory. Once you have that you can have something like this:

```
function remove_image($image_name_with_path)
    {
        if(file_exists(realpath($image_name_with_path))){
            unlink($image_name_with_path);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is just an example